# Date format issues in Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Data coming my sheet through automation date coming like **April 01, 2022 at 01:52PM**

Now i have to convert it standard date time formats like ddmmyyy hhmmss etc how can do this without creating new column for same like any app script do automatic when new row update

Now i have to convert it standard date time formats like ddmmyyy hhmmss etc how can do this without creating new column for same like any app script do automatic when new row update

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you do a `Find an Replace` with "at" substituting it with "", it will automatically change to a date format. And then you can set your custom format as you wish.

[image]

Second row there is just A2+1 to show you now it became a value you can format!